# I can't run VLFeat on matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vlfeat

I am trying to install vlfeat-0.9.20 in Matlab 
but i have the following error

any help, please?
[image: error message]

> > run('C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2010a\vlfeat-0.9.20\toolbox\vl_setup')
> >     Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2010a\vlfeat-0.9.20\toolbox\mex\mexw32. 
> >     In path at 110
> >       In addpath at 87
> >       In vl_setup at 78
> >       In run at 57

And after adding the toolbox of VLFeat and also after to compile the VLfeat before using setup command it also gave me the following error

[image: compiling error]

Comment: @SardarUsama  it didn't work it got this error vl_compile could not be found.

Comment: Apparently VLFeat  is not in your MATLAB search path. It must be added in the search path

Comment: @SardarUsama how can I add it  regards?

Comment: Read the [](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-remove-or-reorder-folders-on-the-search-path.html)

Comment: @SardarUsama
also didn't work

Comment: You have to **compile** the VLFeat library first before setting it up for the first time.  `vl_compile` should come with VLFeat.  Part of VLFeat's instructions is to include the VLFeat directory as part of your search path.  Sardar in his link above shows you the way.

Comment: @rayryeng 
I also did that but it gave me the error message  which I added it in the question